# How do I link Docker containers running under Plesk Onyx?

Tags: docker, plesk

I'm running a Docker container on a Plesk Onyx managed server using the Docker extension. Everything is fine except email. How can I link containers in Plesk so that I can utilize an external smtp server?

Answer (score 0):

How about having a look at for example:

=> https://github.com/tomav/docker-mailserver

Comment: I've looked at that. The hard part is working within the Plesk umbrella. I'm trying now to just re-create the image with the mailserver built in but so far no luck.